# Exception when using mkbundle(mono) to compile Simple Winforms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono, mkbundle

I have tried using `mkbundle --deps f.exe -o d.exe` 
But exceptions are thrown

I get the following errors

```
embedding: I:\f.exe
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\mscorlib.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\Mono.Security.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.Configuration.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.Xml.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.Security.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.Drawing.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\Accessibility.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\Mono.WebBrowser.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\Mono.Posix.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.Data.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\Mono.Data.Tds.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.Transactions.dll
   embedding: C:\PROGRA~2\MONO-2~1.8\lib\mono\4.0\System.EnterpriseServices.dll
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s

Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='sh',
 CommandLine='-c "as -o temp.o temp.s "', CurrentDirectory=''
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartIn
fo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown
>:0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInf
o startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>
:0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start
Info) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.Execute (System.String cmdLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:
0
  at MakeBundle.GenerateBundles (System.Collections.ArrayList files) [0x00000] i
n <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Applica
tionName='sh', CommandLine='-c "as -o temp.o temp.s "', CurrentDirectory=''
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartIn
fo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown
>:0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInf
o startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>
:0
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start
Info) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.Execute (System.String cmdLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:
0
  at MakeBundle.GenerateBundles (System.Collections.ArrayList files) [0x00000] i
n <filename unknown>:0
  at MakeBundle.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Can someone help me.

```
EDIT:
```

The errors above occurred when i used mkbundle directly from Windows from Cygwin i get the following error

```
'as' command not found
```

From the Net i learned 'as' is a Compiler where can i get it,Please help me i'm not a Linux enthusiast

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mkbundle from a Unix-like toolchain (such as Cygwin).

You have to install the `gcc`, `gcc-mingw` and `as` packages in Cygwin.

This is from mkbundle's [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkbundle).